# How can i install openssh on iOS siumlator?

Tags: ios, openssh

I've made some tweaks for iOS.

There are a lot of manuals on "how to install openssh to iphone, ipad". But, there is no one for `ios siumulator`.

I need to execute some executable files on command line.

So I have to connect to iOS simulator.

How can I install openssh on iOS siumlator?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. What are you trying to do, and why can't it be done in Terminal?

Comment: i wrote http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34418332/is-there-a-way-to-control-ios-simulator-gestures-using-terminal a few days ago. but nobody comment this. so i decided to make my self.

Comment: are you sure this is imposible?

Comment: Probably not impossible, but given that on device you have to Jailbreak to get that kind of access, it's unlikely anyone would go to the effort of replicating the same thing on the simulator.

Comment: It's an awful lot of effort just because you don't like the Apple recommended way (and the way thousands of other devs do it) of automating UI Interaction

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i will find another way.